# Get part of URL in PHP is not completely working

Tags: php, url

I've this code here:

```
$url = 'https://www.my-page.de/account/show/4913';

echo substr( $url, strrpos( $url, '/' ) + 1 );
```

This returns me the needed id:

```
4913
```

Now the problem begins. In some cases the URL looks like this:

```
$url = 'https://www.my-page.de/account/show/4913/';

$url = 'https://www.my-page.de/account/show/4913/?conversationId=xxx';
```

This means that my code don't works anymore. So is there any way to be 100 % sure that I always get my ID from the URL? The ID is always at the same position from the beginning on but the end can be different.

**Update**

When I've this code here I'm getting not the last part anymore. Any idea why and how to fix this?:

```
$url = 'https://my-page.de/account/show/4913/';
$id = basename( dirname( $url ) );
```

I just want to be sure that it works in every situation. In this case the selected part is:

```
show
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use functions that are meant for directories and/or URLs:

```
echo basename(dirname($url));
//or 
echo basename(pathinfo($url, PATHINFO_DIRNAME));
//or
echo basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
```

The last one may return the filename if you had `https://www.my-page.de/account/show/4913/index.php` so you would want to use:

```
echo basename(dirname(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)));
```

Lot's of possibilities depending on what you need.  The point is that there are specific functions for working with directories, filenames and URLs so that you don't have to treat them as just strings that have no meaning but unlimited possibilities..

- [Filesystem Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php)
- [URL Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.url.php)

Comment: Can you explain why this works? I've tried it and it works but I'm not sure how. Would be awesome to understand this :)

Comment: As the function names imply, you are getting the directory and then the basename (last one) of that.  Edited for the last one as it may have a filename.

Comment: There is a problem with the function. Any idea why? I'll write it into my question

Comment: Depending on ending slashes you may be better off using `echo basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));` I'm not sure of the variability so you need to test on possible URLs.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `explode()` to turn it into an array, then get the 5th item to get the id:

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://www.my-page.de/account/show/4913/?conversationId=xxx&trey=trey';
    $arr = explode('/', $url);

    $id = $arr[5];

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($id, 1) .'</pre>';
```

then it doesn't matter how many query params there are, they'll always be last

refs:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Oh no, I completely forgot this. That made it, thanks a lot!

Comment: I'll mark your question in some minutes as helpful because there is a timeout I need to wait for

Comment: @Mr.Jo that's cool, though, I'd personally accept abra's answer - so cool

Comment: Okay I'll do this :D